# Intellij Idea fulltext search only in unit and integration test classes?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, full-text-search

<sub>I have faced this problem recently and it took me a while to find out the solution, so I would like to share it here.</sub>

Assume a multi-module Maven project, each module having a standard directory structure:

- `src/main/java`
- `src/main/resources`
- `src/test/java`
- `src/main/resources`

Using IntelliJ Idea, how to perform a full-text in the test classes, i.e. mainly these with either `*Test.java` or `*IT.java` suffix and others (helpers with `*DataHelper.java` suffix) across the modules? The `File Mask` is not an option because it doesn't support logical operations (and, or, not) to find out.

The search scans all the directories across the project:

[image]

Comment: You can also change the File Mask definition in the upper right of the window and type the pattern there...

Comment: As I said, I cannot restrict the search only to the files ending with **any** of `*Test.java`, `*IT.java` and `*DataHelper.java`.

Comment: Go via two or three steps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The small <kbd>Scope</kbd> tab is the key and could be missed at the first glance. The expanded drop-down list offers a variety of scopes to limit the search which can be used alongside the `File Mask` filter. The following selections can be easily overlooked:

- For the test scope, select: `Project test files`
- For the non-test scope, select: `Project production files`

As long as the project is a Maven project, IntelliJ Idea can distinguish scope even for the full-text search.

[image]